# How to always show hint in text field not only when it is clicked in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: login screen]

I have a custom text field but as shown in the picture, the bottom text fields looks so vague and empty, I'd like to keep the hint showing even if the field is not focused, how do I achieve that in flutter?

here is my widget code:

```
 Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      autofocus: true,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xff0E9447), width: 2.0),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xff0E9447), width: 2.0),
                          ),
                          hintText: AppStrings.email,
                          labelText: AppStrings.email,
                          alignLabelWithHint: true,

                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColors.primaryColorLight),
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: I am not sure if I got you right, but by default, `hintText` is visible, even if you hadn't clicked on it.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad  I'm sorry but this is not helpful at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ideally in Flutter you cannot do this as both `hintText` and `labelText` behave in two different ways. `labelText` is shown as `hintText` as long as the user does not focus on it. As soon as the user clicks on the TextField, the `labelText` animates to a specific position whereas a `hintText` remains visible  until the user types something.

So using `labelText` and `hintText` together, does not make any sense as the TextField will wipe of the `hintText` while animating the label.

However with some extra effort, you can use `Stack` widget to solve your problem.

Declare a class variable (a variable within the concerned class, outside any block of code) to store a `TextEditingController`.

```
TextEditingController _controller;
```

And initialize in your class' initState(),

```
_controller= TextEditingController();
```

Solution Code:

```
    Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Stack(
                        children : <Widget>[
                          TextFormField(
                            autofocus: true,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xff0E9447), width: 2.0),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xff0E9447), width: 2.0),
                          ),
                          labelText: AppStrings.email,
                          alignLabelWithHint: true,

                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColors.primaryColorLight),
                          ),
                    ),
                   (_controller.text=="")
            ?
            Text(
              AppStrings.email,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey
           // Style it according to your requirement / To make it look like hintText
         ),
       )
            :
            Container();
               ],
             ),
                  ),
```

Basic Logic of the above code: If the TextField does not have any text then display the (hint) `Text`
widget else don't display anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohit it worked! with only a few modifications list wrapping the Hint text in inkwell and making it request focus to the text field when tapped, because I noticed than when the hint text itself is clicked nothing happens. Thanks again

Comment: You are right Mohit, I think my answer actually doesn't add more value, I must delete it. However I got 1 upvote on it, but I feel it's not worth.

Answer (score 56):

If you would like the label to be visible at the top of the TextField, and the hint displayed at the same time you can simply add:

```
floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always
```

to the **TextFields** **InputDecoration** (decoration).

(At the time of writing this, there is a bug that will only show the hint and suffix upon focus, this has been fixed in a very recent PR and will be available shortly, see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/60394))

**Full Example**

```
TextFormField(
      controller: textController,
      style: theme.textTheme.bodyText2,
      keyboardType: keyboardType ?? TextInputType.number,
      enableInteractiveSelection: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: labelText,
          labelStyle: theme.textTheme.headline6,
          suffixText: suffixText ?? '',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide:
                BorderSide(color: theme.textTheme.bodyText2.color, width: 2),
          ),
          hintText: '0.0',
          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter some text';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (String text) => onChange(text),
    );
```

Comment: "floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always" helped me. Thanks dear.

Answer (score 7):

There is a way around this.
Use the `labelText` property and set `floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never`.

This way you will always see the hint and when the User clicks on the TextField, it goes away.