# labelText not showing whenever I use hintText in combination with it in TextFormField

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to input a mobile number from the user. I want hintText to appear in its place and labelText to appear whenever the user clicks on the textformfield but due to some reason hintText doesn't show up at all!

```
SizedBox(
      width: 280,
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          
          alignLabelWithHint: false,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
          prefixText: '+91',
          prefixStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff191919),
              fontSize: 13,
              fontFamily: 'poppins'),
          hintText: 'Enter your phone number',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff9D9D9D),
              fontSize: 13,
              fontFamily: 'poppins'),
          labelText: 'Enter your phone number',
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color:Color(0xffF25C54),fontSize: 10),
          fillColor: Color(0xffEBC9AC),
          filled: false,
        ),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter your phone number';
          }
        },
        onSaved: (value) => mob = value,
      ),
    );
```

Can someone help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: Where do you see that? I tested your code on iOS and the hint text shows up perfectly

Comment: on my android device! Is there a way to change the padding of the label text? Maybe it's too less for my android and it's blocking the hint text.

Comment: The code you pasted worked correctly for me, maybe the problem is some place else? Can you paste a screen capture?

Comment: Thanks for your time I got the answer. We can't have both hint and label at once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759041/how-to-always-show-hint-in-text-field-not-only-when-it-is-clicked-in-flutter

Comment: Likely I misunderstood your question... glad you found the answer.